# How to apply different sort options for different categories in woocommerce wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting, woocommerce

I need to apply different sorting options for different categories in `Woo-commerce`. For e.g. `Category-A` has default sorting by `Name`, `Category-B` has default sorting by `Price Low to High`, and `Category-C` sorted default by `Newness`.

Comment: Corrected formatting.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby` filter to change the default order-by value.

To check which category is being displayed. you can use `is_product_category` function.

The value inside the `is_product_category` should be your category slug and of course you can use several category to check at once by using this function as follow:

`is_product_category( array( 'category-a', 'category-b' ) )`

```
add_filter('woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby', 'custom_default_catalog_orderby');

function custom_default_catalog_orderby()
{
    if (is_product_category('category-a')) {
        return 'price'; //you can use either date or popularity or rating , price or price-desc
    }
    if (is_product_category('category-c')) {
        return 'rating'; //you can use either date or popularity or rating , price or price-desc
    }
    if (is_product_category('category-c')) {
        return 'title'; //you can use either date or popularity or rating , price or price-desc
    }

}
```

the code above is tested you just need to change the category slug based on your need and place the code inside your functions.php